# Way to remove elements in json file using R

Tags: r, json

Is there a way to remove elements from a JSON using R?

Here's an example of a file I'm working with:

```
[
    {
        "var1_id": 1,
        "var2_id": 2,
        "var3_id": 3
    },
    {
        "var1_id": 4,
        "var2_id": 5,
        "var3_id": 6
    },
    {
        "var1_id": 7,
        "var2_id": 8,
        "var3_id": 9
    }
]
```

I want to use R to remove the line for var2_id in each list, while keeping var1_id and var3_id. How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest would be to convert to `data.frame` with `fromJSON`, remove the column (`select`) and use `toJSON` to convert to JSON

```
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)
fromJSON(str1) %>% 
   select(-var2_id) %>%
   toJSON(pretty = TRUE)
```

-output

```
[
  {
    "var1_id": 1,
    "var3_id": 3
  },
  {
    "var1_id": 4,
    "var3_id": 6
  },
  {
    "var1_id": 7,
    "var3_id": 9
  }
]
```

#### data

```
str1 <- '[
    {
        "var1_id": 1,
        "var2_id": 2,
        "var3_id": 3
    },
    {
        "var1_id": 4,
        "var2_id": 5,
        "var3_id": 6
    },
    {
        "var1_id": 7,
        "var2_id": 8,
        "var3_id": 9
    }
]'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can achieve what you want without passing to a R object, using the **jsonStrings** package. You have to use a [JSON patch](https://jsonpatch.com/):

```r
library(jsonStrings)

str1 <- '[
    {
        "var1_id": 1,
        "var2_id": 2,
        "var3_id": 3
    },
    {
        "var1_id": 4,
        "var2_id": 5,
        "var3_id": 6
    },
    {
        "var1_id": 7,
        "var2_id": 8,
        "var3_id": 9
    }
]'

jstring <- jsonString$new(str1)

patch <- '[
  {"op": "remove", "path": "/0/var2_id"},
  {"op": "remove", "path": "/1/var2_id"},
  {"op": "remove", "path": "/2/var2_id"}
]'

jstring$patch(patch)$asString(pretty = TRUE) |> cat()
# [
#     {
#         "var1_id": 1,
#         "var3_id": 3
#     },
#     {
#         "var1_id": 4,
#         "var3_id": 6
#     },
#     {
#         "var1_id": 7,
#         "var3_id": 9
#     }
# ]
```